Dropdown menu built with Vue and Tailwind not working on Firefox
I have a dropdown menu in page header, this is the code (I'm using Vue 3 and Tailwind):
<header class="w-full fixed z-40">
    
    <div class="flex justify-between lg:table w-full px-5 relative z-30 h-12">

      <Transition name="slide-bottom">
        <nav class="float-left absolute top-10 pt-4 lg:pt-0 left-0 lg:left-5 lg:top-0 w-full lg:w-fit" v-if="menuShowCp">
          <ul class="lg:flex justify-between items-center">
               
            <template v-for="(item, i) in menu">
              <menu-item v-if="item.show" :name="item.name" :subMenu="item.subMenu" :link="item.link" :class="{ 'lg:pr-20': i == menu.length - 1 }" class="xl:pr-0"> 
                <component :is="item.icon" class="inline-block" />
              </menu-item>
            </template>

          </ul>
        </nav>
      </Transition>
    </div>
</header>

This is the menu-item component (simplified):
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  const menuShow = ref(false);
  defineProps(['name', 'subMenu', 'link']);
</script>

<template>

  <li class="menu-item group relative p-2 px-4 lg:p-0" @mouseover="() => menuShow = true" @mouseleave="() => menuShow = false">

    <span class="absolute hidden lg:block w-full h-full z-20"></span>

    <RouterLink :to="link || '#'" class="block relative my-2 py-1 px-2 xl:px-3 z-30 rounded transition cursor-pointer">

      <slot />

      <Transition name="slide-right">
        <span class="inline-block ml-2">{{ name }}</span>
      </Transition>
      
      <Transition name="slide-left">
        <img src="/images/spark.png" v-if="menuShow" alt="Spark" class="absolute -top-1 left-5">
      </Transition>

    </RouterLink>

    <Transition name="slide-bottom">
      <ul class="relative lg:absolute rounded-b-md menuArrow z-10 min-w-full" v-if="subMenu" v-show="menuShow">
        <template v-for="menu in subMenu">

          <li v-if="menu.link && menu.show" class="hover:translate-x-1 transition-all">
            <RouterLink :to="menu.link" class="inline-block w-full py-2 px-3">{{ menu.name }}</RouterLink>
          </li>

          <li v-else-if="menu.subMenu" class="pt-3 last:pb-3">
            <span class="pb-2 px-3">{{ menu.name }}</span>
            
            <ul>
              <template v-for="sb in menu.subMenu">
                <li class="hover:translate-x-1 transition-all w-fit whitespace-nowrap">
                  <RouterLink :to="sb.link" class="inline-block w-full pt-1 px-3">{{ sb.name }}</RouterLink>
                </li>
              </template>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </template>
      </ul>
    </Transition>

  </li>

</template>

<style scoped>

  .menuArrow::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    content: ' ';
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #002777;
  }

  * { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }

</style>

On Chrome and Edge it works properly:
GIF showing the behaviour on Google Chrome
But on Firefox I get this behaviour:
GIF showing the behaviour on Firefox
Even when I remove the mouseleave event, it still dont let me click, so I don´t think it is related to the mouseover event:
GIF showing the behaviour on Firefox without the mouseleave event

I haven't used Vue or Tailwind, but I've seen similar behavior when there's a gap in the menu layout. Even one pixel is enough. When the pointer enters the gap, it's technically not hovering over the menu, so the menu closes. Can you investigate the menu layout by disabling the popup autohide (e.g., with Browser Toolbox)?
